# Carriage return in DataReceivedEventArgs

Tags: c#, carriage-return

I am running a console process attached to my C# application using UseShellExecute and redirecting the output to my application. I have the OutputDataReceived event handled.

Now if the console process return data containing a carriage return (like in case of chkdsk the completion percentage is updated on the same line of console window), the event handler function does not receive the carriage return character in the DataReceivedEventArgs.Data

Is there a way to enable getting carriage return in the data received?

Comment: Why do you need to enable getting the carriage return? There is implicitly a carriage return at the end of the data every time the event is raised. That's what `ReadLine` does for any `StreamReader` and its why the method to start reading the output asynchronously is called `BeginOutputReadLine`.

Comment: @mike-z, Every line read has an implicit carriage return and also, most have a _new line character_ as well. Now I want to distinguish just carriage return from carriage return with new line character. As I mentioned in my post, _chkdsk_ command or _format_ command print the completion percentage on the same line on console. I want to mimic that behavior while writing the content read in a rich text box.